# Sending user data from Qt application to server

Tags: qt, network-programming

I am working on a desktop application written in Qt that does not connect to the internet (apart from through a third-party licencing application). I would like to ping a server with a piece of identifiable user information (e.g. their software key, email, IP) every time a user logs on, so it is possible to can track how many people are using the software.

I have very little experience with network programming but Qts API looks promising (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-programming.html). More generally, because I am very concerned about degrading existing user experiences with firewall popups, or security issues of sending data from their desktop / network, is there anything further related to this to be aware of? Many guides go through the steps to setup a TCP connection for example, which looks trivial, but do not go into details on these kind of wider issues.

If anyone can reccomending reading on this issue it would be much appreciated as am a bit lost where to start.

Comment: AFAIK, QtNetwork does not handle SSL by itself. You will need to link SSL library. That will be a bit of pain in the ass.

Comment: Qt has [these classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ssl.html) for working with SSL.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. If the application/system doesn't connect to the Internet, how are you going to reach the server? Did you mean the computer is connected the the Internet but the commercially licensed software currently does not connect to Internet? What happens when the computer isn't connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look to [Qt examples and tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtexamplesandtutorials.html), and more specifically those for [networking](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/examples-network.html). The solution will depend of what you will have on the server side (API, socket, ping ?).

In all cases, you will trigger the firewall when you contact your server, there is no way to avoid it.

In matter of security, use HTTPS and if your server support it, better use TLS than SSL protocol.
Latest Qt version [support both SSL 3 and TLS 1.2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsslsocket.html), .